# TableViewCell borders created disappear when highlighted

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I found on this forum a method that can create a border from ether side of a view, with I applying on my labels in my cell when it created in cellForRowAtIndexPath

the problem is when i select the cell the lines I created are gone, when I deselect the cell I can see the line again.

I had an issue when the cell is selected the labels text color in the cell get change to white but u fixed this with the method setSelected , with help me save cell labels colors before it selected. the problem is it dosent work the same way

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    [self saveTextColors];
    [self saveLeftBoarders];
}

- (void)saveLeftBoarders {
    [self addLeftBorderWithColor:[UIColor grayColor]  Width:1.0 andView:amountV];
    [self addLeftBorderWithColor:[UIColor grayColor]  Width:1.0 andView:amountPay];
    [self addLeftBorderWithColor:[UIColor grayColor]  Width:1.0 andView:date];
    [self addLeftBorderWithColor:[UIColor grayColor]  Width:1.0 andView:month];

}
- (void)saveTextColors {
    UIColor *leftPayColor = self.leftPay.textColor;
    UIColor *amountVColor = self.amountV.textColor;
    UIColor *monthColor = self.month.textColor;
    UIColor *amountPayColor = self.amountPay.textColor;
    UIColor *dateColor = self.date.textColor;

    self.leftPay.highlightedTextColor = leftPayColor;
    self.amountV.highlightedTextColor = amountVColor;
    self.month.highlightedTextColor = monthColor;
    self.amountPay.highlightedTextColor = amountPayColor;
    self.date.highlightedTextColor = dateColor;
}
- (void)addLeftBorderWithColor:(UIColor *)color Width:(CGFloat) borderWidth andView:(UIView *)view {
    UIView *border = [UIView new];
    border.backgroundColor = color;
    border.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, borderWidth, view.frame.size.height);
    [border setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];
    [view addSubview:border];
}
```

this code is from the cell.m
in the method cellForRowAtIndexPath I run the same method to create the border line.

**as I type this question I saw in the debugView that this creates a problem of creating that border over and over again but is still not visible,
after deleting the border creation in the cell.m I saw in the debug view hierarchy  that the border is there ( from it creation in cellForRowAtIndexPath)  but it not visible.
what is the problem ?**

Comment: `[view addSubview:border];` clearly not a good idea in a cell. Why not using a property? And in prepareForReuse(), "clean it"? Also, what about override setHighlighted?

Comment: to tell the truth I did, but I dont see any difference between setHighlighted to setSelected ( tried each method with same content and didnt see something changed ). why addSubview is not a good idea ? and I didnt understand the rest, what to make a property ? the border itself ? ( it can actually work ) but just in case what do you mean by "prepareForReuse(), "clean it"" I dont know this method

Comment: Okay, cells are reused. That's a concept (in UITableView/UICollectionView) you should know and look for if needed. Also, in debug view, is the frame of the border correct?

Comment: ow right, yes I know cell are reused, and I checked again my table view, if I scroll down and up and open debugView I can see more lines adding up. I think I will add them as view from the nib, it will save me the trouble, didnt expect that much problems from a single line. thanks for your time !

Comment: Try Using 

setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool)

Method where you will set its border when cell is highlighted.

Comment: I tried, same effect as setSelected.